# Any meds to increase blood pressure?

Tags: blood-pressure

Are there any meds , aside from caffeine , that increase blood pressure . I know physical exercise can produce a temporary increase but I am wondering about something that can increase it for hours. Starting with a pressure like 60/40 ?  Assume hydration and electrolytes are good .

Comment: Yes, there are, but a pressure of 60/40 usually indicates a severely ill individual who needs immediate medical attention, quit possibly in an ICU. Could you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: fludrocortisone comes to mind.

Comment: The medical industry is unable to help ; See a cardiologist  regularly ( 3 days  ago). Typical BP , 6 AM =  189/ 110 then 7 AM= 73/43  ( today) , and low for the rest of the day. I am sure an ICU would screw me up worse.

Comment: Sounds like an autonomic problem. See neurologist.

Comment: The GP Dr did not like the fludrocortisone for me. I have asked the oncologist for his ideas,

Comment: Now 63/44, , any other ideas ? I have had about 1000 mg of caffeine today, plenty of water and salt . I did take 80 mg verapamil yesterday because of morning BP of 176/105. Pulse is normally 55 to 70.(  I am old - 80).